# Si británico se refiere a lo natural del Reino Unido, ¿cuál es el gentilicio para lo estrictamente de Gran Bretaña?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, definiciones, gentilicio

Dice la [RAE.es](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=nswBSk5HRDXX2253EtHi):

> **británico, ca**. (Del lat. Britannĭcus).
>
> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la antigua Britania, sur de la Gran Bretaña.
> 2. adj. **Natural del Reino Unido de Gran Bretaña e Irlanda del Norte.** U. t. c. s.
> 3. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a este país de Europa.

En tal caso, ¿hay algún gentilicio para denominar a lo perteneciente o relativo *estrictamente* a Gran Bretaña *y no* a Irlanda del Norte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si eres británico pero no eres de Irlanda del Norte, entonces eres inglés, galés o escocés.

A causa del carácter de exclusión del gentilicio que buscas, y también de que el nombre de la isla coincide con una de las denominaciones usuales para todo el reino, no hay una sola palabra. Aparte de las tres posibilidades mencionadas más arriba, no encuentro otras que "británico no irlandés" o "británico de la isla de Gran Bretaña".

Comment: Sí, ¿pero no hay ninguna palabra que englobe estas nacionalidades *excluyendo* irlandés del norte?

Comment: Trata de imaginar lo mismo referido a España: si no eres isleño ni de Ceuta o Melilla, eres peninsular. Pero ¿cuál es el gentilicio de los que son de todas partes _excepto_ de Canarias? O ¿cómo se llaman los que son Canarios pero no de la isla de Gran Canaria?

Comment: Sí, veo tu punto. Pero siguiendo con el paralelismo, peninsular sería británico en el sentido etimológico (de Gran Bretaña), por lo que me cuesta pensar que no hay una palabra específica para los habitantes de la isla de Gran Bretaña.

Comment: Me gusta lo que comentas. Te sugeriría añadirlo a la respuesta inicial para completarla y así marcarla como respuesta aceptada. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Paco, los españoles de todas partes excepto de Canarias se conocen como _Godos_ :)

Answer (score 4):

> Reino Unido.
>
> Nombre abreviado del Estado europeo formado por Escocia, Gales,
>   Inglaterra e Irlanda del Norte, cuyo nombre oficial completo es Reino
>   Unido de Gran Bretaña e Irlanda del Norte: «Este boxeador había
>   desafiado a los campeones de Francia, de Alemania y del Reino Unido»
>   (Mendoza Ciudad [Esp. 1986]). Su gentilicio es británico, **que
>   también lo es del territorio específico de Gran Bretaña**: «Los
>   laboristas del primer ministro británico, Tony Blair, subieron once
>   puntos en relación con otra encuesta publicada hace una semana»
>   (Nacional [Ven.] 2.10.00).»

[Real Academia Española: Diccionario panhispánico de Dudas. Madrid: Santillana, 2005, págs. 318-319, 364, 567]

Answer (score 1):

Según el DPD:

> Inglés: gentilicio propio de Inglaterra que, extensivamente, se usa
>   también como gentilicio de Gran Bretaña (Inglaterra, Gales y Escocia)
>   y del Reino Unido (Inglaterra, Gales, Escocia e Irlanda del Norte).

Comment: Fíjate en que, antes de eso, habla de que es frecuente extender el significado *en el habla corriente*. Es decir: la RAE refleja ahí un uso, pero esto no significa que sea correcto.

Comment: Es muy interesante, porque se observa como el significado original ha ido mutando a medida que las fronteras han cambiado.

Answer (score 1):

En Colombia no se hace distinción en el gentilicio a menos que se especifique,  **británico** se usa para denominar a cualquier entidad, objeto, costumbre, persona, etc. del conjunto que conforma el Reino Unido.  Británico es todo hasta que se especifica su origen,  por ejemplo:

> Mr. Callum MacDonald es británico porque viene del Reino Unido.  ¡Ah!,
>   pero es de Glasgow,  luego ¡es escocés!.

Comment: Gracias por el apunte.