# ¿Cómo se puede traducir "claim farms" al español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Resulta que se está extendiendo una práctica curiosa entre los jóvenes británicos ([del Reino Unido, vaya](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5064/1674)) que quieren que sus vacaciones de verano les salgan baratas, cuando no gratis: de acuerdo con una ley de protección del consumidor de Reino Unido, se pueden denunciar servicios hasta tres años después de haberlo utilizado, sin que sea necesario utilizar pruebas demasiado contrastadas.

Al parecer, esto se utiliza para denunciar a cadenas de hoteles arguyendo que allí cogieron una enfermedad por una comida en mal estado o cosas así.

Todo esto lo comento porque en la noticia [Los hoteles de Benidorm buscan sangre en las toallas para atajar la estafa británica](http://www.elconfidencial.com/espana/2017-02-19/benidorm-hoteles-estafa-claim-farms-britanicos-rincon-de-turismo_1334195/) lo explican y mencionan quién está llevando a cabo estos procesos:

> Así las cosas, las populares ***claim farms*** británicas -firmas de abogados buitre que han puesto en jaque antes a sectores como el del automóvil o la sanidad pública- han aprovechado el vacío legal para hacer foco en el turismo. Se anuncian incluso en grandes carteles en el metro: "¿Unas malas vacaciones? Llámenos, conseguiremos su dinero de vuelta".

Lo que me resulta curioso es el concepto de *claim farms*, por lo que inmediatamente me he puesto a pensar en palabras equivalentes en castellano.

La traducción directa sería *granjas de reclamación*, pero *farm* también puede traducirse como *centro*, *semillero*, *reserva*. Así las cosas, visualizo opciones del estilo *recolectores de quejas*, pero no me convence del todo porque entiendo que el concepto *claim farm* no solo incluye la parte de "recolectarlas" sino también la de gestionarlas.

¿Cuál os parece que sería una buena traducción del concepto?

Comment: I do not think I have ever heard or seen the phrase used in Britain. The only similar one I remember is ambulance chasers but I think that is out of date now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo lo traduciría literalmente por "**granjas de reclamaciones**" o "**granjas de demandas**". Entiendo que `claim` puede ser traducido de muchas maneras (aunque posiblemente *denuncia, demanda* o *reclamación* son las más relevantes en este contexto) y que tu reserva es sobre el uso de "granja".

Como bien apuntas (copiando libremente de la pregunta):

> [...] **farm** también puede traducirse como centro, semillero, reserva. [...] entiendo que el concepto `claim farm` no solo incluye la parte de "recolectarlas" sino también la de gestionarlas.

Es una buena observación, centrada en la gestión razonable de un negocio o producción. Sin embargo creo que el uso de "granja" en este término no sería como el de "cómo gestionamos (bien) una granja", es decir: "tenemos unas vaquillas, las cuidamos, ellas nos dan leche que embotellamos y procesamos con cuidado, etc".

Creo que aquí el concepto de granja es más **peyorativo**, en plan "tengo a los animales hacinados pero me da igual. Que den leche y huevos a más no poder que lo que tengo aquí es un negocio". Irónicamente (o no) sería el uso de [*ordeñar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R9uLDKZ) en su tercera acepción:

> Obtener el máximo provecho posible de algo o alguien.

Es decir, cuando "ordeñar" llega a "exprimir".

Creo que muchas de estas granjas funcionan más a base de cantidad que calidad. Cuando tienes muchas demandas saturas a otros gabinetes de abogados o gestorías, o a la administración misma, y terminas ganando no porque tu reclamación tenga más o menos base, sino por la falta de recursos del sistema o de la otra parte para procesarla.

Existen otros tipos de granjas, como "[Click farms](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2013/aug/02/click-farms-appearance-online-popularity)". De [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_farm):

> a large group of low-paid workers are **hired to click** on paid advertising links

Fíjate que estos clicks fraudulentos (en publicidad o "Likes" de Facebook) no los hace un *bot* sino un humano en un país subdesarrollado de forma manual. Por eso son "granjas". Tienes ahí a "nosecuantas" personas, hacinadas en habitaciones, dándole a un click una y otra y otra vez.

La primera vez que yo oí de estas granjas fue en referencia al juego World of Warcraft (creo). Básicamente, en estas granjas la gente hacía click y click y click para realizar algunas de las tareas más básicas del juego, como cortar leña. Por esta acción, al personaje del juego le daban una moneda de oro (o cobre o lo que fuese). El señor (real) que trabaja en la granja se pasa el día haciendo click y click y click y digamos que consigue 1000 monedas de oro virtuales, que luego a se venden por un $1 (o lo que sea) real a otros jugadores del juego. Ese era el modelo de negocio de la granja: convertir repetitivos clicks en dinero.

Ya por último otro artículo-referencia: [With Click Farms Where Workers Sit In Dingy Rooms, Bars On The Windows, Generating 1,000 Likes For $1](http://www.businessinsider.com/how-low-paid-workers-at-click-farms-create-appearance-of-online-popularity-2013-8)

El título lo dice todo. Los trabajadores están casi como ganado.

Entiendo que este no es el caso de la gente en Reino Unido, pero el concepto de "Farm" con esas connotaciones procede del mismo sitio: tener a la gente casi esclavizada para producir en masa.

Creo que es ese "modelo de producción" lo que define a esta entidad y por eso lo traduciría como "granja", con esas connotaciones tan peyorativas.

Comment: According to Wikipedia the English phrase _server farm_ can be translated literally as _granja de servidores_ so that adds weight to your suggestion. We also have _wind farms_ but I see that you use _parque_ for them.

Answer (score 4):

Mi humilde sugerencia: "Usinas de reclamos" (aunque debo reconocer que el término "[usina](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bBSZVbI)" puede ser algo localista). Si no, "fábricas de reclamos".

Comment: _Usina_, nunca lo había oído. Y qué gracioso que sea una palabra de origen francés que no caló en España. Lo de _fábrica de reclamos_ me parece muy apropiado.

Comment: Mientras que en español más regularmente usamos _fábrica_ los portugueses si adoptaron la palabra _usina_ Me gusta la respuesta de **fábrica de reclamos**

Comment: Creo que el término refleja el concepto de inventar reclamos, parecido a la "litigation industry" en EE.UU.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que lo que hacen estas empresas es gestionar las reclamaciones, yo propondría ***gestorías de reclamaciones***. No queda tan pintoresco como *granja*, eso sí.

En todo caso, me preguntaba si una *claim farm* no sería parecido a lo que en España es una *oficina de defensa de los derechos del consumidor*, como la OCU o FACUA, que se encargan de gestionar las quejas y reclamaciones de los consumidores. Lo que pasa es que estas entidades suelen ser organizaciones no gubernamentales o asociaciones, más que empresas.